# Vue.js interface for sketchup

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, sketchup

Sketchup uses html for its extension user interface.
I'm trying to make an interface with vue.js + vuetify.
Sketchup can render the page but I can't send data to javascript.
Sketchup sends data to javascript by calling a function and passing data.

Vue.js invokes an action callback when it's mounted.
Sketchup then executes the function updateUI(data). At this moment the interface throws an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: updateUI is not defined
    at index.html:1

This is my main.js file where Vue is initialized and the updateUI function is declared.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import shared_data from './stores/shared_data';

function updateUI(data){
  shared_data.data.parameters = data.parameters;
}

Vue.config.productionTip = false

var gui = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is index.html after webpack

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
   <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8>
      <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
      <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico>
      <title>my-app</title>
      <link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
      <link rel=stylesheet href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
      <link href=C:/Users/**/my-app/dist/css/chunk-vendors.0c9ceaf8.css rel=preload as=style>
      <link href=C:/Users/**/my-app/dist/js/app.6b29f88e.js rel=preload as=script>
      <link href=C:/Users/**/my-app/dist/js/chunk-vendors.a37f46e5.js rel=preload as=script>
      <link href=C:/Users/**/my-app/dist/css/chunk-vendors.0c9ceaf8.css rel=stylesheet>
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript><strong>We're sorry but my-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
      <div id=app></div>
      <script src=C:/Users/**/my-app/dist/js/chunk-vendors.a37f46e5.js></script>
      <script src=C:/Users/**/my-app/dist/js/app.6b29f88e.js></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the function you want to call to the Window object, making sure it remains a global function and doesn't get wrapped inside an anonymous module when you build your JS.

```
window.updateUI = function(data){
  shared_data.data.parameters = data.parameters;
}
```

You can also example a complete set of example in this github repo: https://github.com/SketchUp/htmldialog-examples (Example 4 introduces Vue.)